Bulk Update Custom Metadata Records
Are there any sfdx/sf CLI commands to bulk update the Custom Metadata Records via VS Code?
I can able to see only create commands in the Salesforce documentations.
Thanks In Advance!!

To update metadata records, you can use any of the normal methods, such as project deploy start, or right-click (context menu) SFDX: Deploy This Source To Org. The purpose of the create function is to act as a parallel to other functions (e.g. apex generate class), so you don't need to manually create the record files to begin with.

Thank you for the answer. Let's say I have a CSV file of custom metadata data, can we use it in VS Code to update my actual custom metadata records?

@Loki_72 There's no direct CLI or VS Code command, but this answer provides an example shell script that you could use to perform bulk updates (the commands in the answer have been deprecated, though, so you'll need to do some translation to modern commands).

Okay, Thanks!!! @sfdcfox
